# Multiple required fields in Channel Form without setting required in CP

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor

I need to set multiple fields as "required" in Channel Form/Zoo Visitor, but I can't find anything in the documentation that describes how to do this. I can't set the fields to be required in the CP because validation needs to happen at form level, not entry level.

None of the following works:

rules:field_1|field_2=“required"
rules:field_1=“required"|field_2=“required"
rules:field_1=“required" rules:field_2=“required"

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Would something like [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax works:

`rules:field_1="required" rules:field_2="required"`

The problem was to do with Field Pack radio buttons, which aren't validating properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#rules-my-field-name) the required rules should work. If they don't I'd recommend posting a bug report [here](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/submit).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your rule formatting

```
rules:field_1="required"|field_2="required"
```

I'm not sure that type of condition is allowed in the rules parameter